# не срабатывает валидация validate js при ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-validation

У меня есть ajax запрос, и валидация (плагин validate js). Сама валидация не срабатывает. Помогите пожалуйста. Тут работает, кстати. А вот у меня на проде нет. В чем примерно может быть проблема?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.call_block button').on('click', function() {
    var data = $('.call_form').serialize();
    $.ajax({
      url: 'callback.php',
      type: 'post',
      data: data,
      dataType: 'json',
      beforeSend: function() {
        $('.call_block button').button('loading');
      },
      complete: function(data) {
        $('.call_block button').button('reset');
      },
      success: function(data) {

        $('.call_form input.error').removeClass('error');
        $('.call_form .error_span').remove();

        if (data.status == 0) {

          $.each(data.html, function(index, value) {

            $('[name=\"' + index + '\"]').addClass('error');

            $('[name=\"' + index + '\"]').after(value);

          });

        } else {

          $('.call_form').empty();

          $('.call_form').append(data.html);

          $('.call_form').append(data.botton);

        }

      },
      error: function(request, status, error) {
        console.log(error);
        if (data.status == 0) {
          $('body').prepend('<div class="alert alert-danger fade in"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i> Ошибка при отправки формы <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button></div>');
          setTimeout(function() {
            $(".alert").alert('close');
          }, 5000);
        } else {}
      }
    });


    return false;

  });

  $('.call_block .call_form').validate({

    rules: {

      inputPhone: "required"

    },
    messages: {
      inputPhone: "Пожалуйста, введите номер Вашего телефона",

    },
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-validation@1.19.1/dist/jquery.validate.js"></script>

<section class="call_block">

  <form class="call_form">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove close"></i>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="inputName">Меня зовут</label>
      <input type="text" name="inputName" class="form-control" id="inputName" placeholder="Имя">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="inputPhone">Мой телефон<font class="red-text">*</font></label>
      <input name="inputPhone" type="text" class="form-control" id="inputPhone" placeholder="+7-999-999-99-99">
      <input name="input_url" type="hidden" value="">
      <!--fix form-->
    </div>
    <button onclick="gtag('event', 'obratnaya',{'event_category': 'obratnaya', 'event_action': 'clicks'}); yaCounter28233771.reachGoal ('svyaz_to'); return true;" class="btn btn-block">Перезвоните мне</button>
  </form>

</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте валидатор в /body переместить, у вас и сейчас не работает так как jquery не срабатывает.

Comment: Так тоже пробовал. Не срабатывает. Решил проблему другим путем. Убрал return false. Все равно, спасибо Вам за обратную связь.